# <tenantname>.b2clogin.com redirects to login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have replaced login.microsoftonline.com with .b2clogin.com in our application -
https://ourtenant.b2clogin.com/ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/our_policyname/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

When we click on the login button, from our application, it is redirecting correctly to ourtenant.b2clogin.com but in the response, it redirects to login.microsoftonline.com. Is that correct behavior?

[image]

**Response -**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a seriously old version of user flows, that is deprecated. You should upgrade to the current version of user flow, by setting up a new user flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions#how-to-switch-to-a-recommended-user-flow